# What test can I use to compare for discrete counts from two independent samples

Tags: nonparametric

I need some assistance. Its driving me crazy. So I have two independent populations, I sample them at different points to obtain ordinal count data. However, at each point the sample sizes used to estimate the counts are unequal. I beleieve that affects the count at that point. What test can I use to compare both populations adequately after obtaining count results after sampling about 5-15 times?

Comment: What is your research question?

Comment: Is there a difference between two groups of cells based on a particular treatment, I can only obtain a few cells to check their phenotype from each group at a certain point. Hence the unequal sample size.